# Angular HttpClient - Handle empty and non-empty responses

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Assuming we have `http: HttpClient`, I would like to provide a service call wrapper method as follows:

```js
public async post<T>(url: string, body: any): Promise<T> {
    // do some stuff

    const response = await this.http.post<T>(url, body, this.options).toPromise();

    // do more stuff

    return response
}
```

This works as expected for any `T` except `void`. The behavior I was hoping for (and am still looking to implement) is to not return any value (`Promise<void>`) when the server returns no response. I'm now wondering what the best way to implement this is without having a different function for empty response bodies.

I assume there's no way to disambiguate based on the generic type? I tried looking for ways to do that, but it seems there's no way to do it, which makes sense given what TypeScript does and how it works. Fwiw, the type would be available at the call-site (as in, I would be calling that method as `service.post<void>(...)` in the case I expect an empty response body).

One thing I was wondering is if I could always make it return a string (`responseType: "text"`) and then parse the JSON manually. Then I could check the status and response string, if they were `200` and `""` respectively I would know that I can return `undefined`. *If* that was the right way to go (and I'm not sure that it is) there are a few questions I have:

1. Would manually parsing the JSON have a performance drawback?
2. What method should I use to parse it? What does the `HttpClient` use?
3. How would I make sure that error handling works the same as if it happened from within the `HttpClient.post` method? Ideally I wouldn't want it to deviate from the error mechanism inside of `HttpClient.post`.

Or is there another simple way that I'm missing to implement the desired method? Are any of my assumptions false?

Comment: Not related, but is there a reason for making this a Promise, instead of using just the observables you get?

Comment: I just like promises more. I'm mainly a C# programmer and `async`/`await` fit my mental model very well, I find it easier to think with them compared to observables. It's not set in stone and if it would somehow help with this I wouldn't mind changing it, but as you said it's probably unrelated to my issue.

Comment: have you found way around it? I am also stuck on this issue.

Comment: @chintanadatiya Only what I mentioned in the answer below. I don't know of another way to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out this is only an issue if the server returns `200`. If the server returns the "no content" status `204` (which is appropriate for an empty response body) then `post` returns `null`. I would have preferred `undefined` to distinguish from an actual `null` JSON response (since `null` is a valid JSON token), but it is what it is, and what it is is good enough for me.

Comment: This does not answer your own question, so it should not be posted as answer IMO

Comment: I admit it may not sound obvious from the question, but the entire question revolved around `http.post` erroring on `<void>`. But it does not error if the server returns `204`, which seems to be the intended way to use the API. It may not answer the question, but it makes the question irrelevant. What is the correct thing to do? Delete the question? Close it?